# Magento 2.2 Build system

Tags: static-content, deployment, setup-di-compile, static-content-deploy, magento2.2.0

I trying to setup build system for `setup:di:compile` and `setup:static-content:deploy` based on official devdocs.

> **Build system**
>
> The build system compiles code and generates static view files for
>   themes registered in Magento. It doesn’t need a connection to the
>   Magento database; it needs only the Magento codebase.
>
> On your build system:
>
> 1. Pull the shared configuration file from source control.
> 2. Use the magento `setup:di:compile` command to compile code.
> 3. Use the magento `setup:static-content:deploy -f` command to update static file view files.
> 4. Check the updates into source control.

I have prepared docker image ([bmxmale/magento2-php:2.2-cli](https://hub.docker.com/r/bmxmale/magento2-php/)) and running docker with mounted magento code, without access to DB.

Before I exec `magento app:config:dump` and settings are now stored on **config.php** and **env.php**

Run docker with mounted Magento:

```
docker run -it -v $HOME/www/magento2:/srv/magento2 bmxmale/magento2-php:2.2-cli bash
```

Try to compile DI

```
magento@578fc8d10f6d:/srv/magento2$ magento setup:di:compile


  [Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                                                                     
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known  



  [PDOException]                                                                                  
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known  



  [PDOException]                                                                               
  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known  


setup:di:compile
```

Anyone know how build system should look like to make build code like described on [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/deployment/pipeline/technical-details.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Working build system

Based of [issue 10041](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10041) for RC version I figure that we need to remove `env.php` file if exist.

Second [issue 11372](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11372) throwing error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPackage() on null in /srv/magento2/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PostProcessor/CssUrls.php on line 217

Error: Call to a member function getPackage() on null in /srv/magento2/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PostProcessor/CssUrls.php on line 217
```

This is caused by previously genereated cache on `var/view_preprocessed`, to fix this we need to remove cache:

```
rm -rf pub/static/* 
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/pub
```

## Full steps to deploy static content on build system:

#### Run container with mounted our magento

```
docker run -it -v $HOME/www/magento2:/srv/magento2 bmxmale/magento2-php:2.2-cli bash
```

#### Remove cache

```
rm -rf pub/static/* 
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/pub
```

#### Deploy static content for backend

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US -t Magento/backend
```

#### Deploy static content for frontend

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f da_DK -t OurTheme/default
```

Comment: pub/static/*  remove .htaccess and symlinks!!! This isn't correct command. Better is:
pub/static/adminhtml/*
pub/static/frontend/*

Comment: @PatrykPadus rm -rf pub/static/* doesn't remove the .htaccess and is mentioned in the docs