# Error in content deploy in magento 2.2.1

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

I have installed the magento 2.2.1 but on deploying static content it is giving following error

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPackage() on null in /var/www/html/unicorn-magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PostProcessor/CssUrls.php:215
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/unicorn-magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PostProcessor/CssUrls.php(109): Magento\Deploy\Package\Processor\PostProcessor\CssUrls->getValidExternalUrl('{{base_url_path...', Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#1 /var/www/html/unicorn-magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PostProcessor/CssUrls.php(80): Magento\Deploy\Package\Processor\PostProcessor\CssUrls->parseCss(Array, 'css/email-inlin...', 'frontend/Custom...', '@import url("{{...', Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#2 /var/www/html/unicorn-magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(147): Magento\Deploy\Package\Processor\PostProcessor\CssUrls->process(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array)
#3 /var/www/html/unicorn-magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(103):  in /var/www/html/unicorn-magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PostProcessor/CssUrls.php on line 215
```

I have removed view_processed content, pub/satatic and tried multiple times but this error is showing. Please help to resolve this. Thanks

Comment: Magento tried to run getPackage function on some object which is equal null. Try to find out why this object is null using xdebug...

Comment: @Nitin Pawar did you find out the reason?

Answer (score 14):

This is [**already answered**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/196959/3535) here by @MateuszLerczak

I am quoting the relevant part from the answer below:

> Workaround for that is remove generated data before deploy. If
>   `var/view_preprocessed` exists magento using data from this dir.
>
> rm -rf pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/pub/*
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US

Also see this **[GitHub thread](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11372)** for more details

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a magento bug :-( . The way to reverse it is the following (I know this is not a solution) but it will help to have the site working again:

On command line:

**Magento ≥ 2.2**

> php bin/magento config:set dev/css/minify_files 0
>
> phpbin/magento cache:clean

**Magento < 2.2**

On DB (mysql client) execute:

> UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 0 WHERE path = 'dev/css/minify_files'
>
> bin/magento cache:clean

Now, you can compile again.

Answer (score 2):

[issue 11372](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11372) throwing error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPackage() on null in /srv/magento2/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PostProcessor/CssUrls.php on line 217

Error: Call to a member function getPackage() on null in /srv/magento2/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PostProcessor/CssUrls.php on line 217
```

## Full steps to deploy static content on system:

#### Remove cache

This is caused by previously genereated cache on `var/view_preprocessed`, to fix this we need to remove cache:

```
rm -rf pub/static/* 
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/pub
```

#### Deploy static content for backend

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US -t Magento/backend
```

#### Deploy static content for frontend

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US -t OurTheme/themeName
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the existing static content did not help for me, but deploying with standard strategy, instead of quick did:

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f -j 4 -s standard`

Edit: it looks like the error did not go away, and the reason it didn't fail has nothing to do with the strategy. Repeated tests show that if deploying using multiple jobs (-j 4) the error is still there but it doesn't stop the deployment process.